# Autofill in Excel with Protected cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a logbook for drivers that come in and out of my warehouse.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 2 Or Target.Column = 4 Or Target.Column = 6 Or _
      Target.Column = 8 Or Target.Column = 10 Then
        Sheets("POR DIA").Cells(Target.Row, 12) = Now
    End If
End Sub
```

When I try to block the last cell that autopopulates with date and time the macro comes to a halt and won't input the information since the cell is blocked.

What can I do to prevent the current user from modifying that cell but still autocomplete that cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can temporarily unprotect the sheet

```
Sub Unprotect()
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    ' Do your stuff here
    ActiveSheet.Protect
End Sub
```

If it has a password, use `ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"`

To unprotect/protect a specific sheet use this syntax `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect`

It might be better still to use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Password", _
 UserInterfaceOnly:=True` - the userinterfaceonly allows VBA to make changes but not the user. Also I think this behaves better if the code is interupted for any reason

Comment: I am 1% familiar with this topic. I actually just learned I could insert a code to my Excel. I just wanted to clarify my situation. The workbook I have cells B/C are merged as well as D/E, F/G, H/I, J/K, L/M. when any of those merged cells are modified it autofills L/M withe the current date and time. How can I prevent the Drivers from modifing that autofilled cell? If I block the cells it  block the autofill, but if I use that code I assume they would still be able to modify it?

Comment: Yeah if you use the last part of my answer, it should work as expected. The code can edit the cell but the user can not. Anyone who has access to the code can easily get around it though! There are ways to protect your VBA code - just google it and it should be simple enough.